# Querying a SQL Server in Excel with a parameterized query using VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, parameterized-query

I'm trying to query a table in Microsoft Excel using VBA. I've written up some code to try and accomplish this task, but I keep getting a run-time error '1004' saying it's a General ODBC error. I'm not sure what I need to do to get this code to run properly so I can query this table.

I'm using SQL Server Express, the server I'm connecting to: `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Database:

[Databaselink](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780735666054-files/9780735666054_files.zip)

Querying the products table
VBA Code:

```
Sub ParameterQueryExample()
'---creates a ListObject-QueryTable on Sheet1 that uses the value in 
'        Cell Z1 as the ProductID Parameter for an SQL Query
'        Once created, the query will refresh upon changes to Z1. 

Dim sSQL As String
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim rDest As Range


'--build connection string-must use ODBC to allow parameters
Const sConnect = "ODBC;" & _
    "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
    "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
    "Database=TSQL2012;" & _
    "Trusted_Connection=yes"


'--build SQL statement
sSQL = "SELECT *" & _
        " FROM TSQL2012.Production.Products Products" & _
        " WHERE Products.productid = ?;"


'--create ListObject and get QueryTable
Set rDest = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
rDest.CurrentRegion.Clear  'optional- delete existing table


Set qt = rDest.Parent.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
    Source:=Array(sConnect), Destination:=rDest).QueryTable


'--add Parameter to QueryTable-use Cell Z1 as parameter
With qt.Parameters.Add("ProductID", xlParamTypeVarChar)
    .SetParam xlRange, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z1")
    .RefreshOnChange = True
End With


'--populate QueryTable
With qt
    .CommandText = sSQL
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True  'add any other table properties here
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With


Set qt = Nothing
Set rDest = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this Stack Overflow question with a Google search. It does not look like anyone has tried answering it, so here's what I ended up doing. Instead of using "QueryTable", use an ADO command object as done in [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181734).

MSDN Example:

```
Dim Conn1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd1 As ADODB.Command
Dim Param1 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim Rs1 As ADODB.Recordset

Dim i As Integer

' Trap any error/exception.
On Error Resume Next

' Create and Open Connection Object.
Set Conn1 = New ADODB.Connection
Conn1.ConnectionString = "DSN=Biblio;UID=admin;PWD=;"
Conn1.Open

' Create Command Object.
Set Cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
Cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn1
Cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Authors WHERE AU_ID < ?"

' Create Parameter Object.
Set Param1 = Cmd1.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, 5)
Param1.Value = 5
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Param1
Set Param1 = Nothing

' Open Recordset Object.
Set Rs1 = Cmd1.Execute()
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution :) I was looking into this for you