# Visual Basic Access - recording information from Textboxes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a form that allows you to register users. I've looked up tutorials and none of them seem to work. This is the code I am stuck with currently:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblUser(User ID, Fullname, Username, Password, Security) " _
     & VALUES & " (" & Me.ID & ",'" & Me.Fullname & "','" & Me.Uname & "','" & _
     Me.uPass & "','" & Me.Pri & "')"
```

When I run the code I get:

> Runtime error '3134': Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: Instead of executing the statement, print it out and make sure it's valid SQL. That being said...better to use parameterized queries.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678856/querying-a-sql-server-in-excel-with-a-parameterized-query-using-vba

Comment: `VALUE` there should be a string (`"VALUE"`), not unless it is a variable containing the string `"VALUE"`.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

1. You have space in one of your field. Use brackets if you have space
   or if you use reserved words.
2. VALUES must be included in the string, not as a varible.

Correction:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblUser([User ID], Fullname, Username, Password, Security) " & _
    "VALUES (" & Me.ID & ",'" & Me.Fullname & "','" & Me.Uname & "','" & _
    Me.uPass & "','" & Me.Pri & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

From my comment, try below:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblUser(User ID, Fullname, Username, Password, Security) " _
     & "VALUES(" & Me.ID & ",'" & Me.Fullname & "','" & Me.Uname & "','" & _
     Me.uPass & "','" & Me.Pri & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Password is a reserved word, so:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblUser(User ID, Fullname, Username, [Password], Security) " _
```