# Execute a query once for an entire column instead of looping through all cells

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, ado

I use the loop below to go through a column and perform a query for each cell value. Given the amount of cells in this column can easily exceed 10'000 rows, this is not a very fast method and therefore I am looking into another method for a performance boost.

I am thinking about populating an array with the cells' values, but with this method it would most likely still be necessary to iterate through said array and perform the query for each iteration.

I am not familiar with any method to possibly execute the query once, or at least to significantly boost performance for this procedure. Any ideas?

```vb
Public Function getdata(query As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim connstring As String
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

connstring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=noneofyourbusiness;Connect Timeout=180"
cnn.Open connstring

Set getdata = New ADODB.Recordset
    getdata.CursorLocation = adUseClient
getdata.Open query, connstring, 2, adLockReadOnly
End Function

Sub start()
'code...

For Each c In sht.Range("J3:J" & LRow)
    If Not c.Value = "" Then
        'Query
        Set rs = getdata("SELECT 'Checked' FROM astAssetTypes AT JOIN astAssetTypesUDFV UDFV ON UDFV.TableLinkId = AT.Id WHERE UDFV.Userfield13Id = '5029' AND AT.Code = '" & c.Value & "'")
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            sht.Cells(c.Row, "L").CopyFromRecordset rs
            With sht.Range(sht.Cells(c.Row, "A"), sht.Cells(c.Row, LCol)).Font
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
            End With
            rs.Close
        End If
    End If
Next c

'code...
End Sub
```

Comment: There are a number of options.  Don't think of your Excel rows as something special.  They are just data.  If you have dbo on SQL you could link/import your data there (probably fastest).  If not, can you load Excel and SQL data into memory, process everything and dump it out.  Don't use manual tint and shade, use conditional formatting.  Looping isn't what is slowing you, its the constant loops back to SQL and the writing to Excel.  If (with 10k rows) this takes more than about 30 seconds you need to optimise.

Comment: @Gareth please write an answer, would be helpful. As for the CF, I specifically opted out for that: it needs to be non-dynamic formatting

Comment: You really need to parametrise that statement. SQL injection is ***still*** a far too large a problem in the industry even now, and it shouldn't be. Sandboxing, development work, school projects, etc aren't "immune" to be parametrised; get in the habit now of writing code that isn't just a huge security flaw and then in the future it won't be a problem when you're writing something that will "matter" if it has a giant vulnerability in it.

Comment: @Larnu I agree, but have never practised save SQL injection (it so far has not been necessary as the connection is read only and is only used by a small nr. of users within the company). If you show me a save method, I will happily implement it

Comment: A quick [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=VBA+parametrise+SQL+query) led me to [Querying a SQL Server in Excel with a parameterized query using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678856/querying-a-sql-server-in-excel-with-a-parameterized-query-using-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Sub start()

    Dim strCodes$, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cell As Range

    '// Generate "IN" clause
    For Each c In sht.Range("J3:J" & LRow)
        If Len(c) > 0 Then
            strCodes = strCodes & "'" & c & "'" & IIf(c.Row = LRow, "", ",")
        End If
    Next

    'Query
    Set rs = getdata( _
        "SELECT 'Checked', AT.Code FROM astAssetTypes AT JOIN astAssetTypesUDFV UDFV ON UDFV.TableLinkId = AT.Id " & _
        "WHERE UDFV.Userfield13Id = '5029' AND AT.Code IN (" & strCodes & ");")
    While Not rs.EOF
        Set cell = sht.Columns("J:J").Find(rs("Code"), LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            If rng1 Is Nothing Then
                Set rng1 = sht.Cells(cell.Row, "L")
            Else
                Set rng1 = Union(rng1, sht.Cells(cell.Row, "L"))
            End If
            If rng2 Is Nothing Then
                Set rng2 = sht.Cells(cell.Row, "A").Resize(, LCol)
            Else
                Set rng2 = Union(rng2, sht.Cells(cell.Row, "A").Resize(, LCol))
            End If
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    '// Dump result
    rng1.Value = "Checked"
    With rng2.Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks great Johny. This seems simple and fast. Any thoughts on which of the two methods would be fastest?

Comment: I'll do that once I am back in the office. Need a steadier internet connection to accurately test both methods

Comment: @TimStack Good luck! ;)

Comment: Please don't reject the edit- it is set to SQL code formatting now, I have changed it to VBA. And thanks! Will pick an answer as soon as I have compared both methods @Gareth

Comment: @TimStack I missed a button) Approved!

Answer (score 1):

Method 1.

If you have dbo on SQL then create a temp table and load the Excel data there.  Do it in a single pass using an efficient string building method (ie use Mid to replace rather than constant concatenating).  Or use Integration to load the data directly.  Run the query and drop the data back.  Work out which cells need to be formatted and do them at once (loop with Union to get one big range).

Method 2.

Use a client-side cursor, load all your data from SQL and use rs.Filter to find the matching record.  You could load your Excel data into an array or disconnected recordset and drop it back in.

The significant thing is not to write back to Excel unnecessarily.  There should be no more than two writes to Excel.

Something like (code not fully tested)

```vb
Dim rsLocal As ADODB.Recordset ' create a local, disconnected recordset
Set rsLocal = New ADODB.Recordset
rsLocal.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsLocal.Fields.Append "L", adVarChar, 1024, adFldIsNullable ' change to suit your data
rsLocal.Open

Dim myRange As Range

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
'bring all the records back into memory
Set rs = GetData("SELECT 'Checked', AT.Code Code FROM astAssetTypes AT JOIN astAssetTypesUDFV UDFV ON UDFV.TableLinkId = AT.Id WHERE UDFV.Userfield13Id = '5029' AND AT.Code = '")


For Each c In sht.Range("J3:J" & lrow)
    rsLocal.AddNew
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        rs.Filter = "Code='" & c.Value & "'" 'use Filter to prevent lots of round trips
        If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            rs.MoveFirst
            rsLocal("L") = rs("Code")

            'add the cells to the range as we go
            If myRange Is Nothing Then
                Set myRange = sht.Range(sht.cells(c.Row, "A"), sht.cells(c.Row, LCol))
            Else
                Set myRange = Union(sht.Range(sht.cells(c.Row, "A"), sht.cells(c.Row, LCol)), myRange)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    rsLocal.Update
Next

rsLocal.MoveFirst
sht.Range("L3").CopyFromRecordset rsLocal 'write all updates at once

With myRange.Font ' do all formatting at once
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
End With
```

Comment: As edited.  It won't fully solve your problem (depends on the size of your SQL data) but should some ideas.

Comment: `If myRange Is Nothing` Beg your pardon, but don't see the assignment to `myRange` before this line

Comment: @JohnyL Because the range has never initialised it will default to Nothing.  You could set it to Nothing explicitly but it shouldn't be needed.