# Query to select records that do not appear in DB

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, adodb

I am trying to add missing data to the DB and am therefore trying to collect this missing data through queries.

In my excel sheet I have two columns: `col A` is populated with component codes, while `col J` holds its respective asset type codes.

I want to find all non-existing component-asset type combinations **in one query**.

Currently, I am looping through the excel sheet like in the following example:

```vb
arr = Range("B3:J5000")
For i = 1 To 5000-2
    Set rs = cnn.Execute("Select Top 1 AT.Code From astComponents C Join astAssetTypes AT ON AT.Id = C.AssetTypeId Where C.Code = '" & arr(i, 1) & "' And AT.Code = '" & arr(i, 9) & "'")
    If rs.EOF Then
        'Missing data was found
    End If
Next i
```

This is however not to my satisfaction. I want to end up with a recordset with the component-asset type combinations that are missing. This would significantly improve the speed of my program (120 times as fast)

I tried to use `Except` but this resulted in no records where I did expect them:

```
Select Distinct C.Code, AT.Code 
FROM dbo.astComponents C 
JOIN dbo.astAssetTypes AT ON AT.Id = C.AssetTypeId 

WHERE (C.Code= '0738.D100' AND AT.Code = '0738.M00_03.03') Or (C.Code= '0738.D101' AND AT.Code = '0738.L00_04.04')

Except Select C.Code, AT.Code From astComponents C Join astAssetTypes AT ON AT.Id = C.AssetTypeId
```

**EDIT**
As already mentioned, the desired output should be the missing component-asset type combinations. Example:

```
Component      Asset Type
0738.D101      0990.D10_03.03
0150.C101      0738.L00_04.04
```

**[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6fbb0)**
**Task**: check whether the component-asset type combinations below exist in the fiddle database. If not, add these combinations to the output.

```
Component      Asset Type
0738.D100      0990.D10_03.03
0738.D101      0990.D10_03.03
0150.C101      0738.L00_04.04
0738.L004      0738.M00_03.03
0990.D103      0738.M00_03.03
```

Comment: Can you post the table definitions, some sample data, desired output etc...

Comment: Since they are distinct codes something built around keys comes to mind, Dictionary maybe, for if key exists don't do anything, if it doesn't, add the record.  You could also build a "recordset" along the way of missing recordsets this way.  It is likely looping and more tedious code than using DB functions like JOIN and MERGE.  But if I was doing the recordset analysis in Excel I might approach it this way.  Unique says keys to me, fast and easy.  FYI - wouldn't meet your single query: It's a query PULL (1st), compare in Excel, INSERT (2nd Query or DB statement).

Comment: @SeanLange added Fiddle, example expected output and test data

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code I reckon a single query would be possible. I am able to do it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56673239/10540017) but I had not yet encountered such combinations..

Answer (score 0):

**Not the final answer, as the method below is SLOW**

In this method I use a loop that populates a variable which helps populating a temp table with all component-asset type combinations which should be checked. I then compare the values in the database with the temp table using a CTE.

Creating the temp table and executing the second query lasts for 5 seconds (with 1250 records in `#Temp`), which I deem to be too slow

```vb
arr = Range("B3:J" & LRow)
For i = 1 To LRow - 2
    ComponentCodeTemp = ComponentCodeTemp & "Insert Into #Temp (Component, AssetType) Values ('" & arr(i, 1) & "','" & arr(i, 9) & "');"
Next i

'Query
Set rs = getdata("Create Table #Temp(Component nvarchar(50) Collate Latin1_General_BIN, AssetType nvarchar(50) Collate Latin1_General_BIN) " & ComponentCodeTemp & _
    "; With Compare As (Select T.* From #Temp T), DBD As (Select Distinct Compare.Component,  Compare.AssetType From astComponents C Join astAssetTypes AT ON AT.Id = C.AssetTypeId Right Join #Temp Compare ON Compare.AssetType = AT.Code And Compare.Component = C.Code Where C.Code is null) " & _
    "Select * From DBD")
```

A better markup for the SQL query:

```
WITH 
    Compare AS (
                Select T.* FROM #Temp T
               ),
    DBD AS (
            Select Distinct Compare.Component,  Compare.AssetType From astComponents C
            Join astAssetTypes AT ON AT.Id = C.AssetTypeId
            Right Join #Temp Compare ON Compare.AssetType = AT.Code And Compare.Component = C.Code
            Where C.Code is null
            )
Select * From DBD
```