# Cannot resolve the collation conflict error with Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to list a number of missing records in the DB, [as described in my unanswered question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775570/query-to-select-records-that-do-not-appear-in-db)

I am now attempting to fill a temp table with data that should be checked, and comparing that with the data in the DB. My query is as follows:

```
create table #Temp
(
    Component nvarchar(50),
    AssetType nvarchar(50)
)

Insert Into #Temp (Component, AssetType) VALUES
  ('0990.LB00.000.06', '0738.D100.M00.60_03.03'),
  ('0738.D100.L00.55', '9211.D108.D07.01_02.02');


WITH DBD AS (
            Select distinct C.Code Comp, AT.Code AssetType From astComponents C
            Join astAssetTypes AT ON AT.Id = C.AssetTypeId
            Where (C.Code = '0990.LB00.000.06' And AT.Code = '0738.D100.M00.60_03.03') OR (C.Code = '0738.D100.L00.55' And AT.Code = '9211.D108.D07.01_02.02')
            ),
     Compare AS 
            (
            Select T.* FROM #Temp T
            Left Join DBD ON DBD.Comp = T.Component AND DBD.AssetType = T.AssetType
            Where DBD.Comp is null
            )

Select * From Compare
```

The expected output is as follows, because this component-asset type combination does not exist in the database

```
Component             Asset Type
0990.LB00.000.06      0738.D100.M00.60_03.03
```

However, I am presented with the error

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 22
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_BIN" in the equal to operation.

Comment: Did you try searching for that particular error message? It's pretty clear. You need to match both collations to be able to do any type of comparisons between string types.

Comment: Which is the problem expression?

Comment: @EzLo I did, but I am still too much of an SQL novice to properly comprehend what the solution exactly is. What do you suggest I do, I assume it has to do with setting up the temp table?

Comment: @jarlh it's the CTE, in particular the `Left Join` line

Comment: That problem indicates you have an inconsistent table design. Columns supposed to be compared should be declared with the same collation. (Usually.)

Comment: It runs ok on your fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6fbb0/1 check db collation settings

Comment: The problem here is for temp table you have different collation and for your DB you have different collation, If you use table variable you will not face this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A collation defines a way to compare strings. Whenever you do a comparison between string types (ordering requires comparison too) you need to apply the same criteria, this is the collation type.

```
CREATE TABLE #StringLatin (
    String VARCHAR(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)

CREATE TABLE #StringBIN (
    String VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)

SELECT
    'Oops!!!'
FROM
    #StringLatin AS L
    INNER JOIN #StringBIN AS B ON L.String = B.String
```

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 5 Cannot resolve the collation
>   conflict between "Latin1_General_BIN" and
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

The problem here is the `L.String = B.String`, since both were created with different collation types.

You can solve this by either changing the collation at the table's creation statement (so it matches whichever you are joining against later) or directly at the comparison, inside the `SELECT`.

```
SELECT
    'Works'
FROM
    #StringLatin AS L
    INNER JOIN #StringBIN AS B ON L.String = B.String COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The default collation can change from server to server and it will affect all tables that don't specify a particular collation, which can bring trouble when working with different databases. To find the default collation you can use:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation');
```